# php For some strange reason my password_hash(), does not work

Tags: php

I have a small problem with me PHP code, I've been trying to learn about encryption and internet safety, and so I decided to try it out, my version is currently 5.4.41, the part where it doesn't work is when I type this out, as soon as it gets to it the page fails to complete. 
this is the code,

```
password_hash("password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, 10);
```

pls help me.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` do not exist yet [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

> But upgrading to a new version of PHP would be a better idea. Like PHP7.0 or PHP7.1

Comment: thanks a lot, i would have asked my teacher but he doesn't know about encryption.

Comment: OK, one small point HASH =/= Encryption. You cannot reverse a Hash, you can reverse an encryption